# FILETIME information retrieval on changing timezones

Tags: c++, windows, mfc, filetime

Suppose i have a FILETIME which has some value (which we can see by converting it to systemtime) when I am in timezone1. Suppose I changed my timezone to timezone2.
Now I want to get the time in hours and minutes (format) which was in timezone1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way would be to convert it to system time then use [`SystemTimeToTzSpecificLocalTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724949%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) to convert the time to a timezone specific time.

Comment: the problem is i dont have the older timezone , i can see that the FILETIME value even after changing the timezone is still same , but i cannot compare the hour minute and seconds of it due to change of timezone

Comment: some microseconds have changed so the value of two FILETIME is different, but i know the H::M will be same , so i need to verify that

Comment: @Peter: a file time starts from a constant base, so it should never change: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724290(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: just assume that filetime1 has some value , after second change it beacame filetime2 and also the timezone has now changed, now as only seconds have changed , i would like to compare hour::minute time which should be same , i want to know how to do that